# How can the energy applied to an object differ depending on the reference frame

Tags: special-relativity, energy

This is a question about energy being relative. To accelerate an object travelling at very fast (relativistic) speeds requires more and more energy (as I understand that more and more energy translates into mass rather than speed). But for the object itself it will be at rest in its own frame of reference so from “its” perspective a force applied to it will not have relativistic implications. How can this be explained ?

Comment: Are you asking for an intuitive explanation?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to take special relativity into account to get a scenario where different observers will disagree about how much energy is applied to an object. Here's why.

In a simple scenario where the force vector is parallel to the object's velocity, work is the amount by which an object's kinetic energy changes, and is equal to $F\Delta x$, where $F$ is the force applied to an object, and $\Delta x$ is the total distance the object travels as the force is being applied. Even if the force and the duration of the period over which the force is applied are constant, the starting velocity can still affect how much kinetic energy the object can appear to gain or lose. If the object appears to be moving quickly to one observer, $\Delta x$ will be very large, the force will be applied over a great distance, so that observer will see a lot of energy added to or taken from the object. If an observer sees the object initially at rest, however, $\Delta x$ will be smaller, because the force will be applied over a smaller distance, so less work will be done on it.

Comment: I don't understand what you're talking about. What I'm describing here is a real thing, and it's responsible for the Oberth Effect.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oberth_effect#Description_in_terms_of_work

Comment: @Viesik that is incorrect. Energy is frame variant

Comment: @Veisik you're thinking of momentum, not kinetic energy.

Answer (score 2):

Kinetic energy, or energy, is not an invariant quantity, but is frame dependent, both in relativity *and* classical mechanics.

> But for the object itself it will be at rest in its own frame of reference so from “its” perspective a force applied to it will not have relativistic implications. How can this be explained ?

But there is no meaningful concept as the kinetic energy "in its own frame of reference". You need to specify a frame of reference, from which you can measure the objects kinetic energy, momentum etc.

As measured from within the same frame of reference of the object, or any other frame moving with constant velocity relative to it, its kinetic energy and momentum will be zero.

Comment: @Viesik that is not correct. KE is frame variant in SR, just as it is in Newtonian mechanics

Comment: @Viesik No, it most certainly is not. If velocity $v$ depends on frame of reference, then so to does kinetic energy, $1/2mv^2$

Comment: Right. And relative velocity is different for different observers (moving with different velocities). Therefore, so to is kinetic energy different, for observers moving with different velocities.

Comment: @Viesek you are wrong here. You should listen to Joseph h

Comment: @Dale By the looks of it: what Viesik has in mind is the following: two objects, A and B, and choice of reference frame. The kinetic energy that is attributed to the relative velocity between A and B is independent of the choice of reference frame used to represent the motion of A and B. You can use a reference frame that is (at the start) co-moving with A, you can use a reference frame that is (at the start) co-moving with B, you can use a reference frame that is co-moving with the center of mass of A and B, etc. In total this bookkeeping comprises three frames of reference.

Comment: @Cleonis said “The kinetic energy that is attributed to the relative velocity between A and B is independent of the choice of reference frame” not even that is true if A and B have different mass. In any case, energy is the timelike component of the four-momentum, so it is frame variant just like any component of any four vector.

Comment: @Dale There must be some babylonian confusion here. In an actual collision the kinetic energy of the relative velocity of A and B becomes available for other things. As we know: this is the operating principle of particle accelerators with two counterpropagating particle beams, designed to set up head-on collisions. The amount of energy of the actual collision event is independent of the reference frame that the observer happens to be using.

Comment: @Cleonis the energy that is available for creating particles etc is specifically the energy in the center of momentum frame, which is the invariant mass of the system of particles. That is not the same as the energy in any other frame. There is no if’s and’s or but’s here. Energy is frame variant. It is the timelike component of the four momentum, so its frame variance is indisputable

Answer (score 0):

I think you have answered your own question. In the frame in which an object is moving at non-relativistic speeds, the result of applying a force to it will be an increase in its speed in accordance with Newton's second law. When viewed from another frame moving at a relativistic speed compared with the first, the increase in the speed of the object will be appear to be less. It is simply a manifestation of the relativistic addition of velocities.